# Highcharts custom aggregate methods

Tags: highcharts, aggregate

Can someone post an example of a custom aggregate method in highchart?I want to create a custom aggregate method that groups the following points into a single point with the tool tip ?
I have an array that has the following data 
array1 :['apple',2,4,10,12.5]
I want the above array to be represented in a single grouped point with a tool tip
that shows as follows
apple
no of apples : 2
min:4
max:10
mean:12.5

Comment: Is 'apple'  the x value, and 2 the y value?  You just want to display the additional information in the tooltip?  Will you have mulitple values (i.e. 'orange', 'pear', etc)?

Comment: Yes barbara I will have multiple values as well.I want to group them under a single point.How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would process the data to get it into a format highcharts recognizes and then add the extra data to the point object.  You can reference that extra data in the tooltips formatter function:

```
$(function () {
    var input = [['apple',2,4,10,12.5],
                ['pear',1,5,10,12],
                ['orange',3,4,10,13.5],
                ['grape',4,4,10,11.5]],
        data = [],
        categories = [];

    for (i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
        categories.push(input[i][0]);
        data.push({x: i,
                   y: input[i][1],
                   myMin: input[i][2],
                   myMax: input[i][3],
                   myMean: input[i][4]});
    }
    $('#container').highcharts({
         tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>' +
                    'No. of ' + this.x + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' + 
                    'min : ' + this.point.myMin + '<br/>' +
                    'max : ' + this.point.myMax + '<br/>' +
                    'mean : ' + this.point.myMean;
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        chart: {
            marginRight: 50
        },

        series: [{
            data: data
        }]

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/Du5Nw/

Comment: Barbara ,I cannot incorporate chart type in the following code?I want a single column instead of a single point.http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=UHm1IzSbtV

Comment: @user2844540 - Not exactly sure what you mean by that.  But, I can change the series to be a bar chart.  See http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/Du5Nw/1/

Comment: You didn't have jquery enabled on your fiddle.  Setting it at the chart level works also.

Comment: Thanks a lot barbara for the help.But I want to display a series of points on the Y-Axis with a single X-axis point.Like for example,for the same apple , i have 4 "Y" values /points to be displayed.How do i do it ?

Comment: For example in the above array ['apple',2,4,10,12.5]-'apple' is the x-axis and all the numbers (2,4,10,12.5) represent 'apple' on the chart.How do i plot multiple Y axis points for a single x-axis point?

Comment: I honestly don't know what you're going for here.  An image of what you want it to look like might help.  Earlier you wanted columns instead of points, now you want points? It seems like you would want 4 series, one for each metric (min, max, etc) but that isn't what you originally asked for.  This uses a scatter plot and will show the 4 points for each category, but I don't know if it's what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/Du5Nw/2/

Comment: Thanks barabara.I want something in the similar lines as your above fiddle but I want the dots to be joined with a line and also lets say my array is something like in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=PQdRlrQwAK. I want the dots that u had drawn in the chart to be joined vertically with a line (like for apple ,u have a series of points right ,they should be joined vertically with a line).

Comment: Well, there are multiple ways to achive that.  One would be to have the data all in one series with the nulls between the categories http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/Du5Nw/3/.  But, it's messy and kind of a hack.  Another would be to have multiple series and then style them to all look the same http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/mYJAZ/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot once again.What if i have a dynamic array meaning in the above example,u have only 4 values for apple.What if i have an array like this var array = [['apple',2,5,7],['oranges',1,15],['pears',1,3,8,19]]

Comment: Try it,  jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/mYJAZ/1 handles that fine.  The first example is naming things, so it would need some modifications to test for the existance of the data.  But, it's do-able.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again.I will try it.

Comment: I tried this fiddle jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/mYJAZ/1  when i hover over the second and third points in the first apple/other series(as well) series ,the tool tip does not display any information.Whereas the top and bottom points alone shows the hovered over informaation.Can you please tell me why ?

Comment: I also have an array like the following  var input = [
        ['apple', '055', 12, '113', 14, '218', 5, 5, 14, 10.3, 12]].I have to plot series apple and points marked are 12 for '055',14 for '113',14 for '218' and remaining are y axis points in the above array.When i hover over the tool tip under each point ,it should tell me that under apple series ,it has that y point.lets say if '055' is a point under apple series as i said above, tooltip shld say '055' and then corresponding y axis point which is 12.similarly for other elements in the above array.

Comment: :I have the following example.http://jsfiddle.net/jrNsL/.Why am i not able to see all the points hovered over apple series.I'm able to see only two of the thovered points under apple series.Am i doing something wrong ?Appreciate ur valuable help.Thank you.